# python: help in calculation a proportion of 1's in binary sequence

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python. It randomly generates binary strings of length 10 for host and length 7 for parasites. What i need to do now is find the proportion of 1's  in  each parasite genome and total proportion of 1's in the entire parasite population

```
import random
host_genome_length = 10
parasite_genome_length = 5
host_initial_population=15
parasite_initial_population=10
assert   parasite_initial_population >=0
parasite_initial_chance_1= 0.2
host_initial_chance_1=0.5
hosts=[]
for i  in range(host_initial_population):
    genome= []
    for j in range (host_genome_length):
        if random.random()< host_initial_chance_1:
            genome.append(1)
        else:
            genome.append(0)
    hosts.append(genome)
print "hosts:"
print  hosts

parasites=[]
for i  in range(parasite_initial_population):
    genome= []
    for j in range (parasite_genome_length):
        if random.random()< parasite_initial_chance_1:
            genome.append(1)
        else:
            genome.append(0)
    parasites.append(genome)

for i in range(host_initial_population-parasite_initial_population):
    parasites.append(None)
print "parasites:"
print parasites
```

for example if the output is [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], None, None, None, None, None]

i need proportion of 1's in each sequence
and total proportion of 1 in the entire list?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by proportion in this context. Can you give an expected answer in the example case?

Comment: due you have access to numpy? if so `np.sum(data)/np.size(data)`

Comment: total number of 1's/total number so in example it is :8/10 and i only need it for the parasites

Comment: You didn't mark any answer as accepted, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get only one result at a time, you can do it like this:

```
res = [1,0,0,1,1]
proportion = float(res.count(1))/len(res)
```

If the results are all returned as a list of lists:

```
res = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], None, None, None, None, None]


total = sum([ x.count(1) for x in res if x<> None ]) # ignore the None elements
length = sum([len(x) for x in res if x <> None])
proportion = float(total)/length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#pairs of (oneCount, oneProportion)
def prepare(listList):
    result = []
    for subList in listList:
        sLUnitCount = subList.__len__()
        slOneCount = sum(subList)
        result.append((slOneCount, float(slOneCount)/sLUnitCount))
    return result

#individual proportions
def indivProp(listList):
    indiv = prepare(listList)
    return map(lambda x:x[1])

#total proportions
def totalProp(listList):
    indiv = prepare(listList)
    slOnesCounts = map(lambda x:x[0],indiv)
    totalOnes = sum(slOnesCounts)
    slUnitCounts = map(lambda x:x[0]/x[1], indiv)
    totalUnits = sum(slUnitCounts)
    return totalOnes/totalUnits
```